# Derivative of $~y = 1_{x+b>0}x~$ with regard to $~b~$?

Tags: derivatives

I have a function with the form:

$$y = x  1_{x+b>a}$$, where $a$ is a constant.

I would like to calculate $\frac{\partial y}{\partial b}$ but I am having a hard time in doing so. Does somebody has an idea of how to solve this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

David

Comment: Just split it into $x+b>a$ and $x+b<a$, and use the definition of the derivative at $x+b=a$.

Comment: Is $x$ constant?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel No, x is a variable and b is another variable controlling how many of the values of x are able to "pass" through.

Comment: Then you must really be talking about $\frac{\partial y}{\partial b}$, not $\frac{dy}{db}$.

Comment: Oh yes, you are completely right. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

First, apply the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule).  Then, the [definition of the derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Rigorous_definition).  Finally, recognize the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial b} y &= \frac{\partial}{\partial b} \left( x 1_{x+b>a} \right)  \\
    &= \frac{\partial}{\partial b} \left( x \right)1_{x+b>a} + x \frac{\partial}{\partial b} \left( 1_{x+b>a} \right)  \\
    &= 0 + x \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{1_{x+(b+h)>a} - 1_{x+b>a}}{h}  \\
    &= x \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{1_{ a-b-h < x < a-b}}{h}  \\
    &= x\delta(x-(a-b))
\end{align*}

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot. I have another question. What if $x$ (and therefore $y$) are vectors and $b$ controls which of the elements pass through the tresholding operation?  Would it be the same?

Comment: @DavidRomero : Start with something you can visualize: $x$ and $y$ are $2$-vectors.  Then $y = x 1_{\text{something}}$ and you will have a step along whatever frontier is established by "$\text{something}$".  It isn't essential to the differentiation, but you do need to clarify for yourself what is "$\text{something}$".